# Why always get the wrong DateTime format although I've set it?

Tags: vb.net, parsing, datetime

Why always get the wrong formatting although I've set it?

I think the code is right but does not get the right result.

I have:

```
Private Now_Date As String = Date.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

For today, it should return: **12/05/2012**, right? But I always get: `12/5/2012`. This is also for: **09/05/2012**, and I will get: `9/5/2012`. How I can do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
Private Now_Date As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

You were turning it from a DateTime, to a String, back to DateTime, then back to String.

You should also get into the habit of using `Option Explicit On` and `Option Strict On` in your code. It would have told you that you were trying to save a `DateTime` as a `String`, which would have given you a clue. Your code would have produced the error:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Date' to 'String'.